# UIPageViewController (ScrollStyle) not calling dataSource methods

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I guess I'm unclear how Gestures work with UIPageViewController. I'm trying to set up an app with four different "screens" and decided that UIPageviewController would be a great way to facilitate swiping between them. Here's my method where I perform the setup

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self setWorldWalkViewController:[EGLWorldWalkViewController new]]; //One of the content views

[self setPageView:[[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll 
navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil]];

[self.pageView setViewControllers:@[self.worldWalkViewController,]//Sets the initial view to display, I think.
direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.pageView setDelegate:self];
[self.pageView setDataSource:self];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]init];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.pageView];

currentView = WorldWalk; //Where WorldWalk is an enum value
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Ummm… I hope that isn't too long. Anyway here is the dataSource method:

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
currentView += 1;
switch (currentView) {
    case WorldWalk:
        return [[EGLWorldWalkViewController alloc]init];
        break;
    case MonthlyMarch:
    //There is more but this method isn't even being called so…
```

I know there are some auxiliary things I'm doing wrong here (like putting all that stuff in didFinishLaunching:) but right now I'm really focused on figuring out how to get the navigation working. (The proof-of-concept stage.)

Two things worth noting:

1. The app is being designed for landscape (at this point)
2. I'm not using Storyboards, but each custom view controller has its own XIB

The documentation seems to suggest the pageViewController has the navigation stuff mapped out  and that it just needs data, but when I click and drag nothing happens. My dataSource methods aren't even being called, the documentation is thin here, I feel I'm missing something, so maybe somebody could enlighten me?

Answer (score 6):

This problem occurred for me because I wasn't retaining the page view controller. Make sure you keep a strong reference to it and the methods should be called.